# proving a proposition similar to the Cantor Principle

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

let $I_k = [ a_k,b_k]$ be a family of closed finite sets with $ k \in \mathbb{N}$
such that
$$  I_1   \supset I_2    \supset ......   \supset I_k   \supset  ...... $$
has not an empty intersection

$$$$
what i managed to prove  $$$$we need to prove
that $ \bigcap _{i=1}^{k}I_k\neq \varnothing $ so let's suppose the contrary, suppose that the intersection is empty, therefore it would be enough to prove that $I_1 \supset I_i \hspace{5mm}\forall i \in \{2,...,k \} $

we know that $I_i \supset I_2 \hspace{7mm} $ for hypotesis therefore let's suppose true for induction until i

therefore $I_i \supset I_i \hspace{7mm} $ therefore always for hypotesis  $I_i \supset I_{i+1} \hspace{7mm} \implies  $ $I_1 \supset I_i \hspace{7mm} $

so now we know that $$  \forall x\in I_k  \therefore x\in I_1$$
but also $$   \forall x \in I_k \therefore x \in \{   1,.....,k-1\} $$

therefore being all sets not  empty for hypotesis ( all sets are closed )   we know that in the latest set there is an elemetn that therefore it is member of each set, so the intersection of the family is not empty  contradicting the initial statement

Comment: Your proof is highly unclear for me... but it seems that you didn't prove anything... The idea is to take $x_k\in I_k$ for all $k$. Such sequence is bounded and thus have a convergent subsequence. Denote $x$ the limit. What remains to prove is that, $x\in \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb N}I_k$ (which is straightforward by the fact that the $I_k's$ are closed), and the claim follow.

Comment: if you know that there's an element inside each interval doesn't prove that the intersection is not empty?

Comment: No. For example if $I_k=(0,\frac{1}{k}]$, then $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}I_k=\varnothing $.

Comment: the sets needs to be closed so $0$ would be in each set therefore the intersection is not empty

Comment: I know that the sets need to be closed, but you didn't used it in your proof... I gave you a hint in my first comment on how proving your claim. For the example of my second comment : If $x\in \bigcap_{k}I_k$, then $0<x\leq \frac{1}{k}$ for all $k$. Taking $k\to \infty $ yields $x=0$, which contradict $x>0$. Therefore, the intersection is empty.

Comment: the x in the first comment is the  limit of all subsequences?

Comment: no, just the limit of one convergent sub-sesquence...

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you never at any point used the fact that each interval was both closed and bounded ("finite" as you say). Consequently, your reasoning is flawed, as without those two hypotheses, the result may fail. Surb already gave you an example of how your reasoning can fail when you don't have closed sets. Here's another.

I "claim" that if $I_k=[k,\infty)$ for each $k\in\Bbb N,$ then $$\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N} I_k\neq\varnothing.$$

Let's suppose, to the contrary, that the intersection is empty. Given any $k\in\Bbb N$ and any $x\in I_k,$ we have by definition of $I_k=[k,\infty)$ that $k\leq x,$ so since $1\leq k,$ then $1\leq x,$ and so $x\in[1,\infty)=I_1.$ Thus, for all $k\in\Bbb N$ and all $x\in I_k,$ we have $x\in I_1.$ Similarly, we have for all $k\in\Bbb N$ and all $x\in I_k$ that $x\in I_i$ for any $i\in\Bbb N$ with $1\leq i\leq k-1.$

Since none of the sets $I_k$ is empty, we know that in the latest* set, there is an element, that therefore is member of each set, so the intersection of the family** is not empty, "contradicting" the initial statement.

According to your reasoning, we could therefore conclude that $\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}I_k\neq\varnothing,$ but if that were true, then there is some element in it, say $x.$ Given any $i\in\Bbb N,$ we would have $i+1\in\Bbb N,$ and so $x\in I_{i+1}.$ Thus, $i+1\leq x$ by definition of $I_{i+1}=[i+1,\infty),$ and so $i<x.$ Since $i\in\Bbb N$ was arbitrary, that means that $x$ is a real number that is greater than ***any*** natural number, contradicting the Archimedean Property of the Real Numbers.

---

The asterisks above mark the places that your reasoning went off-track. First of all, *there is no latest set* in the sequence of sets $I_k,$ because the set of natural numbers doesn't have a greatest element. Second of all, you have only showed enough to prove that $$\bigcap_{\substack{i\in\Bbb N\\i\leq k}}I_i\neq\varnothing,$$ which is **not** the result that you are trying to prove.